# facing error in paystack integrattion in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, paystack

Hi I'm trying to integrate paystack in laravel 8 but I'm click paynow button it give following error

```
Client error: POST https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize resulted in a 404 Not Found response:

{


  "status": false,


  "message": "Invalid Split code."


}
```

anyone can help how can i solve this
thanks

Comment: It says 404. That means the url is probably not correct

Comment: i'm follow this article https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack i'm following the same step then how can my url incorrect if url is not correct then which one is not correct

Comment: Can you share a snippet of how you implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the request body? It looks like you're trying to pass a split code when you're initializing the transaction, but the code you're passing either:

1. Doesn't exist on that integration
2. Exists on the integration but maybe in test mode, and you're using your live keys (or in live mode and you're using your test keys)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the PAYSTACK_PAYMENT_URL environment variable to the correct URL for paystack.

At the time of writing this, my .env file has the following entry and is working fine.

```
PAYSTACK_PAYMENT_URL="https://api.paystack.co"
```